# fancybox - Can I pass a parameter to the function linked to a new custom button in the toolbar?

Tags: fancybox

I've created a custom button in the toolbar as instructed here:

https://fancyapps.com/fancybox/3/docs/#faq-3

I want to pass the image ID to the click function - can I do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need to pass anything. This is how you can access trigger element (e.g., the link you clicked to open current image) from anywhere in the code:

```
$.fancybox.getInstance().current.opts.$orig
```

You can add some attribute to your links (like `data-image-id`) and then just read it when needed (from your click event).